# Check if is email and password correct

Tags: php

I need to confirm if is email and password correct , but it work with any password I enter. What's the problem? Here is the code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$hash = hash("sha512", $pass);
$hash1 = hash("whirpool", $hash);
$hash2 = hash("sha384", $hash1);
$password = $hash2;

    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'") or die(mysql_error());
    $count=mysql_num_rows($query);
 if($count==1){

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $username=$row['username'];
  $heslo=$row['password'];
    $_SESSION['valid'] = $username;
if(isset($_SESSION['valid'])){
        $realtime = date("d-m-Y h:i:s"); 
        $session = $_SESSION['valid'];
        echo "<script>    window.location.replace('index.php');
</script>";
header("Location: index.php");
    }else{
        echo "Přihlášení neproběhlo správně";
    }
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Whats up with all the hashes? just sha512 will suffice.

Comment: @Daan It's just test. I know, I'll use sha512 only.

Comment: In your db are you storing the encrypted value for passwords?

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you looked at the generated SQL, and confirmed that is generating the correct results, for instance?

Comment: @RowlandShaw: it must have created the same query again and again, so that's probably not the right place. check the preceeding lines.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath That's certainly the implication, but it's a good place to start to debug as to *why* (as it cuts the code that is "bad" in half)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is that you mispelled "whirpool" it should be "whirlpool"

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesen't work

Comment: @user2808698: debuggin 101: `echo` - "If the given algo parameter contains an algorithm that is not supported, the hash function will return bool(false) and issue a warning."

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code a bit, and this seems to be working. The curly brackets order is the one messing it up for you, as the else points to the incorrect if.

I have added comments throughout the script, so you can see what I'm trying to say.

```
mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass');
mysql_select_db('test');

# You can use your post methods, I've used these for testing.
$email = mysql_real_escape_string('email');
$pass = $_GET['pw'];


$hash = hash("sha512", $pass);
$hash1 = hash("whirlpool", $hash);
$hash2 = hash("sha384", $hash1);
$pass = $hash2;

# Now you can see the PW input  
echo $pass."<br>";

# Nonsense
$password = $pass;

    # By using $sql you can echo your query to see what results would it yield upon running it.
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE em='$email' AND pw='$password'";
    $query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $count=mysql_num_rows($query);

    # Echo stuff to see what their results are
    echo $sql."<br>";
    echo $count."<br>";


    # Let's see if we all got it right?
     if($count==1){

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $username=$row['un'];
    $heslo=$row['pw'];
    $_SESSION['valid'] = $username;

if(isset($_SESSION['valid'])){
        $realtime = date("d-m-Y h:i:s"); 
        $session = $_SESSION['valid'];

        # Commented out for testing purposes. I mean the header.
        echo "all is well";
        //header("Location: index.php");
} // this closes the if(isset... 
} // this closes the while loop
# Note that the curly brackets have changed. Now the else points correctly to the other branch if $count is not equal to 1.
}   else {
        echo "Přihlášení neproběhlo správně";
    }
```

Comment: @user2808698 - can you test this please and see if it works?